# Detect All Beacons in the region and get its data ( REACT NATIVE )

Tags: react-native, ibeacon

Hope you are doing well.

i want to detect the beacons which are in my range. i got the react-native-beacons-manager but its not working.

i have the beacon device. i tested it but not luck.

As per this code its showing only those UUID which i am passing in the region object.

Can anyone help me out how to detect the nearby beacons. the code i got from the library is :

the source link is

> https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager

i just did nothing just console the data using in example in above link.

my code is

```
componentWillMount() {

    Beacons.requestAlwaysAuthorization();

    const region = {
      identifier: 'pBeacon_n',
      uuid: '7BA5D5CE-C416-5FD6-8AAA-919D534E0DC3'
    };



    Beacons.startMonitoringForRegion(region) // or like  < v1.0.7: .startRangingBeaconsInRegion(identifier, uuid)
      .then(() => console.warn('Beacons monitoring started succesfully'))
      .catch(error => console.warn(`Beacons monitoring not started, error: ${error}`));
    // Range for beacons inside the region
    Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region) // or like  < v1.0.7: .startRangingBeaconsInRegion(identifier, uuid)
      .then(() => console.warn('Beacons ranging started succesfully'))
      .catch(error => console.warn(`Beacons ranging not started, error: ${error}`));
    // update location to ba able to monitor:
    Beacons.startUpdatingLocation();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.beaconsDidRangeEvent = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      'beaconsDidRange',
      (data) => {
        console.warn('beaconsDidRange data: ', data);

      }
    );

  }
```

The UUID i am passing to the region is my real Beacon UUID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS simply does not let you search for iBeacon transmissions without specifying the ProximityUUID.  The lowest level native APIs which this ReactNative Module uses have this restriction.  Apple implements it this way as a security restriction to prevent you from scanning for beacons belonging to others.

Comment: Thanks @david for your response. From where i can get ProximityUUID of my beacon and where to apply it. Can you please guide me. really appreciated.

Comment: you must either get the proximity UUID from your manufacturer's documentation or use an Android (or MacOS or Windows) beacon scanner tool to read it, as those platforms do allow you to see all beacons.

Answer (score -1):

use like this you can detect all beacons with out giving uuid and etc, but its not working in ios.

```
startBeacon = () => {
        Reactotron.log('else');
        Beacons.detectIBeacons();
        Beacons.detectAltBeacons();
        Beacons.detectEstimotes();
        Beacons.detectEddystoneUID();
        Beacons.detectEddystoneTLM();
        Beacons.detectEddystoneURL();
        Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion('REGION1')
            .then((data) => {
                Alert.alert('', `Beacons monitoring started!`);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert('', `Beacons start error!`);
            });
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('beaconsDidRange', (data) => {
            if (data.beacons.length) {
                this.setState({ detectedBeacons: data.beacons });
                Alert.alert(`Found beacons!`, JSON.stringify(data.beacons));
            }
        });
    }
```